# import object is expected Error in Golang 1.4.2

Tags: go

I have just upgraded Golang from `1.3` to version `1.4.2`. And cannot compile due to error:

```
../../my/mandrill.go:5: import /path/to/go/home/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/keighl/mandrill.a: object is [darwin amd64 go1.3.3 X:precisestack] expected [darwin amd64 go1.4.2 X:precisestack]
FAIL    folder [build failed]
```

on line `m "github.com/keighl/mandrill"`

```
package my

import (
    "fmt"
    m "github.com/keighl/mandrill"
)
```

I guess some rules of importing have changed in `1.4.2`. But cannot figure out how to change my import code to make it compile.

Comment: "go get -u all" after a big upgrade like that should sort it out.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just delete the old pkg files, usually it upgrades automatically though.

```
rm -rf $GOPATH/pkg/
```

Answer (score 5):

I met this problem too. I deleted the old packages but still get same error. finally I found the old pkg keep get generated by my "sublime text2". after restarted it. everything back to work :p