# Golang go-sql-driver/mysql.a

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" library on CentOS6.6 server.
And import the library:

```
import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
```

Building

```
go build index.go
```

However, an error occurred.

> import /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql.a: object is [darwin amd64 go1.4.2 X:precisestack] expected [linux amd64 go1.4 X:precisestack]

I don't know what this error says.

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934618/import-object-is-expected-error-in-golang-1-4-2), with this kind of error, deleting the `pkg` folder often helps

Comment: Thanks! I tried removing `pkg` folder and reinstall the `pkg` .
However error is not disappearing.
So I tried  `go install github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` .
By doing so, I resolve this problem!