# import object is expected between different go versions

Tags: go, building

I switched from go 1.6 to 1.4.2 for faster compilation. When I recompile the earlier compiled binary of 1.6, I get the following error:

```
import go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus.a: object is 
[darwin amd64 go1.6 X:none] expected [darwin amd64 go1.4.2 X:precisestack]
```

I have already tried `go build -a` - which works without any error. And have also tried `go install -a` and `go build` - both of these commands throw the above mentioned error.

I already know that, if I delete by `go/pkg` folder, then it will work. That is the answer of the [already existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934618/import-object-is-expected-error-in-golang-1-4-2)

I wanted to know, if there is another way to resolve this using go tools, other than deleting the `pkg` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely due to previous compiles. Just delete your $GOLANG/pkg and you are good to go!

> another way to resolve this using go tools, other than deleting the pkg folder.

The go tool chain is unlikely to be modified to handle this corner use case.

Comment: Yes, as I have already noted in my question, I know that if I delete `pkg`, it will work. I want to find a way to resolve this is a more cleaner way by just using `go` tools.

Comment: Why are trying to find a hard way to resolve this? In this case, it's safe to just delete the pkg directory and to my knowledge this is the only way to do what you are looking for. What you are trying to do doesn't fit within a typical use case and I doubt that it will get solved by adding the functionality in the current tool chain.

Comment: Hmm yes, it may not be a typical use case, but shouldn’t `go install -a`, rebuild and install all the dependent packages correctly. And with go being a tool chain, is there a defined set of guidelines which say how we can work across multiple go version. Me personally as a developer, this is fine. However, I wanted to have a generic solution that I can communicate to all my team members who are just using my executable and are not `go developers`.

Comment: @RickyA since the development is happening in parallel between my go-based backend and the rest of the frontend, we just push the commits in and the frontend team just builds/runs again using Makefile - `make clean && make && make run`. So, they aren't using binaries.

Comment: Then add a rm $gopath/pkg to the makefiles

Comment: @RickyA Yes, that would be the best workaround to keep it hidden from the rest of the team.